# get_by_id doesn't seem to get by id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

There is an entity in the Questions table with ID 6544293208522752.
When I try to get this back using Questions.get_by_id(6544293208522752) it returns None.

------ Update

To get the parent, categoryKey is just being passed in as an integer:

```
def questionsKey(categoryKey):
    return ndb.Key('Questions', categoryKey)
```

QuestionID is obtained via a get request, one page sends `question.key.id()`, the other gets it with `questionID = int(self.request.get('ID'))`

Comment: does the entity have a parent?

Comment: Yes, it's stored like this: `question = Questions(parent=questionsKey(category))`. I've tried using `Questions.get_by_id(questionID,parent=questionsKey(questionCategory))`, but still get None

Comment: can you please add how you are forming questionsKey(category), questionID and questionsKey(questionCategory)

Comment: @tony thanks I have added this to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing up string and int IDs? Datastore models can have either, but they're not the same. (The auto-generated IDs are ints but, for example, an ID passed as a URL parameter will be a string and you'll need to convert it.)

Answer (score 1):

because you are storing the entity with a parent you need to provide that to the `get_by_id` function too.

```
entity = Questions.get_by_id(6544293208522752, parent=questionsKey(questionCategory))
```

otherwise you wont get the entity back.